# Is there a way to specify the default value for a column in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity 
class Foo {

@Column
private String productName;

@column
private Date orderedDate;

@Column
private int numHits;
}
```

I would like to specify a default value of productName="Toy" and orderedDate="10 days before" and numHits as "5", so that these translate as 'default' values during hbm2ddl and reflect in the schema.

What annotation should I use, so that I can achieve this in a database agnostic fashion (e.g. for h2, postgres, mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you want a default value for a given column, but you are not interested in the DDL details of how this should be guaranteed by the database, you might just as well simply initialize the field to its default value:

```
@Colum(name="emp_salary")
private double salary = 1500;
```

Wouldn't that work?

Comment: If someone populates it via SQL, then the same restrictions don't hold good as the above constant is modified via the model

Answer (score 1):

Not part of JPA explicitly, though you could include it into "columnDefinition" on @Column (which is obviously datastore-dependent, so a hack). You'd have to rely on vendor-specifics if you want datastore-agnosticity for that with JPA

JDO is the only persistence standard that explicitly allows that and hence is datastore agnostic

Comment: I was aware of the columnDefinition, but as I had mentioned earlier I would prefer a database agnostic solution. I am not sure if I will be able to move my code from JPA to JDO at this stage.